# Type definitions and array

Tags: c++, arrays

I’m working on an assignment with

```
typedef int GradeType[100];
```

I understand the basics but can someone explain this to me so I can have a greater level of clarity as to what this does for the program?

Comment: "Explain" what? You need to specify an explicit and clear problem.

Comment: show the code..

Comment: @Yola - he already did; it's just that he didn't know how to format it as code.  OP: To format as code: blank line before and four spaces at the start of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef int grade[3];
  grade[3] class_A={40,70,60};
```

Is "as same as" :

```
int class_A[3]={40,70,60};
```

`typedef int name` will make you be able to declare a `int` object using the name `name`. This will make your code more *logical* and *readable* in your  current context.

Here is an example of it's usage,

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

typedef int grade[3];
grade class_A={40,70,91};
grade class_B={56, 85, 66};

std::cout<<"Grades from claas A:";
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
std::cout << class_A[i] << "\t";
}
 std::cout<<"\n\n Grades from class B:";

 for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
std::cout << class_B[i] << "\t";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a user-defined datatype name `GradeType` that can be used to create a variable that is an array of 100 ints.

So instead of

```
int myGrades[100];
```

you can use

```
GradeType myGrades;
```